# How to print a single statement as a whole statement in java without splitting it because of having multiple user values inside it?

Tags: java, sql

i m trying to execute a sql command in java where values are taken within the statement from user .For example- update stock set name= + value 1+ quantity = value 2 + where stock_id=?'
here  value 1 and value 2 are taken from user and herei want to execute the whole statement as a single command without splitting it which causes the change in meaning of Update command in sql

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Come on mate, you need to format your question in a way that makes it easy for us to understand what you are wanting, and why its going wrong. Have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
   PreparedStatement stmt = Connection
                .prepareStatement("UPDATE stock SET name = ?, quantity = ? WHERE stock_id=?");

    stmt.setString(1,value1); //1 specifies the first parameter(?) in the query  
    stmt.setInt(2,value2); //2
    stmt.setInt(3, stock_id) //3
```